# What is the anime where a popular soft drink kills people who drink it X times?

Tags: soratobu-yuureisen

I've got this vague memory of an anime movie I saw once a very long time ago (around 1990?) and I'd like to find it—but I've no idea of any names that were mentioned.

A particular unique aspect of the plot was that there was some kind of new popular soft drink that was actually made as a part of an evil plan as people died or disappeared (turned to green sludge?) after drinking it X times. The setting was near-future, and I believe that the focus of the action was on some kind of sea warships, but I don't recall much more—that's why I want to find it! :)

Comment: Do you have any further details, such as art style or the language you originally saw the movie in?

Comment: *Weiss Kreuz* (ep 5?), had some sort of drink name Freude that cause ppl's skins to degenerate. The movie *Flying Phantom Ship* had something called Boa Juice that caused ppl to dissolve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

You may be thinking of an old Miyazaki movie called [**Sora Tobu Yureisen**](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=2484). In the movie, there was a drink called "Boa Juice" which is manufactured by the evil corporation and was really some kind of poison that made people dissolve if you drank enough of it.

[image]

This [blog post](http://blacksun1987.blogspot.com/2010/03/sora-tobu-yureisen-flying-ghost-ship.html) has a really detailed synopsis with lots of screenshots of the movie.